# best practice for implementing json web token

Tags: api, token, jwt

currently learn about jwt (json web token), slowly get the idea. But somethings still bother me,

1.How to make it unique? if a user have always the same token, it means we can copy token from other computer, paste it to another and verify there, right? What is the best practice for that, should we look add the ip-address of client?

2.And should we actually change the token of each first request? *i mean if we login today, the token will be different with login on the day after